# How to create empty files in folder with names and extension from list in file Linux / Python

Tags: python, json, pandas, bash

I have a list of file names in the single file `record.txt` as format like this:

```
/home/user/working/united.txt
/home/user/working/temporary.txt
/home/user/working/fruits.txt
```

I have the only `temporary.txt` file in the json format like `temporary.json` in the other folder which I needed as json

I want to create the all remaining files which are not in folder but present in list `record.txt` so that all the missing files are also there as blank files and at the end I have all three files. `temporary.json` has the data so I cannot generate all the files newly. Just the files which are missing in folder and present in list.
At the end, I want to get like below by python or shell script.

```
united.json 
temporary.json
fruits.json
```

and `temporary.json` still has data

Comment: Where is the [attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/)? Note also that in general, code is more valuable than text when posting a question here. For ex., you tagged the question with python and pandas, but I don't see any of that used in the actual post.

Comment: There are several tasks but no problem or question here. Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This command with "create" the files w/o erasing existing ones:

```
while read i ; do touch "${i%.*}.json"; done<record.txt
```

The modification time of `temporary.json` will change to the current one

Answer (score 0):

in Python, you can use `os.path.isfile` to check if a file exist and then create with `open(filename,'w')`:

```
from os.path import isfile
_createTxtFlag = True
_createJSONFlag = True


with open('temporary.txt') as fil:
    for l in fil.readlines():
        l = l.rstrip() #to remove end of line
        #create .txt files if not exists
        if _createTxtFlag:
            if not isfile(l):
                with open(l,'w') as newFil:
                    pass
        if _createJSONFlag:
            json_name = f"{l.split('.')[0]}.json"
            if not isfile(json_name):
                with open(json_name,'w'):
                    pass
```